# Prevent one user from disconnecting an active remote desktop session

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

I've got a server where a number of users are sharing user logins for a short period of time to prevent too many people from logging in at the same time.

The users are connecting over remote desktop, but the problem is that when one user is busy doing something, another user logs in as the same user and disconnects the active session.

Is there any way of preventing one user from logging in and disconnecting the same username who is already connected to somewhere else?

This is on Windows Server 2008 R2

The reason for limitation is the hardware will only support a small number of users. New hardware has been ordered, but users need to use the system until the new one is available.

Comment: What OS is the server running?

Comment: I've updated the question - Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Please specify the reason for the limitations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do this natively. Windows doesn't know that there are 2 human beings using the same user account.

Answer (score 1):

this is by design? using separate logins will fix this!!

make the users aware that are sharing logins & let them fight it out amongst themselves.

You can also reduce the problem by deciding who will log in as console i.e. mstsc /v:server /console

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the root problem why you need to limit the number of simultaneous connections - but guessing licensing restrictions.

With Group Policies, you can limit the amount of simultaneous connections:
"Limit number of connections"
and "Remove Disconnect option from Shut Down dialog"
maybe "Set time limit for disconnected sessions"
read more at  http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc770884%28WS.10%29.aspx

That way you would make it impossible for users to Disconnect the session, keeping the license count small, and limit the number of simultaneous sessions anyway. The goal must be to use personal logons, though.

Shared logon once again proves itself to be a bad idea. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Buy the appropriate licensing. Sharing logins for a non-trivial application is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by allowing simultaneous logons. I use acronyms, sorry. 
Go to GPM, "computer config\admin templates\windows components\ RDS\RDSH\ connections\Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single RDS Session" and then disable or set max #.

Thom Haste

Comment: How does that prevent users from logging in?